# Particle Effect keeps playing(turned off looping and switched stop action to destroy)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development

I am trying to create a deatheffect for enemies. I instantiate the particle system when they are killed. After that the particle system plays but keeps playing,  But I only want it to play ones and then stop playing.

I turned of looping and set stop action to "destroy".

[image: ParticleSystem]

Answer (score 0):

It might have some sub-emmiters or the object may have particles in children. What you need to do is to Destroy(gameObject) when not needed.